# Use instagram as blog, without authentication everytime, instagram API asp.net

Tags: asp.net, instagram

I'm trying to read up on instagram's API, but I don't get any smarter by that.

Because what I want to do basically is to show all my pictures from my instagram for the users of the website.

They don't authenticate, they don't know it's instagram.

Is that possible?

Comment: Is it a public profile or private profile ?

Comment: Public profile.